# Data is not updated using PHP postgresql

Tags: php, postgresql

I created a web project using php postgresql, and i tried to implement a edit and update function on the website. When i tried to edit the data, and click submit, the data won't update. When i tried to debug it, it shows no errors, the code working fine, it's just the data that i edited won't update. What did i do wrong?

The store function :

```
<?php
    

    //echo "$id";
    $id = $_GET['id_stasiun_operator'];
    $var_a_st=$_POST['submit_true'];

    $stasiun = "SELECT id_stasiun, nama_stasiun FROM station";

    $result_station = pg_query($connection, $stasiun);

    $option_stasiun = "";

    while($row_stasiun = pg_fetch_assoc($result_station)){
        $option_stasiun .="<option value='{$row_stasiun['id_stasiun']}'>{$row_stasiun['nama_stasiun']}</option>";
    }
    echo "Value of var_a_st: $var_a_st";
    echo "Value of id : $id";
    if($var_a_st == "Submit"){
        $id_stasiun = $_POST['id_stasiun'];
        $keterangan = $_POST['keterangan'];

        $queryUpdate = "UPDATE station_operator SET id_stasiun = $1, keterangan = $2 WHERE id_station_operator = $3";

        $result = pg_query_params($connection, $queryUpdate, array($id_stasiun, $keterangan, $id));

        if(!$result){
            die("Error in SQL query: " . pg_last_error());
        }
        echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV=\"refresh\" content=\"0; URL=list.php\">";
    }
?>
```

The view :

```
<?php
    $sub_judul = "Edit data";

    $id = $_GET['id_station_operator'];

    //echo "$id";

    $query = "SELECT * FROM station_operator
    JOIN station ON station.id_stasiun = station_operator.id_stasiun
    JOIN operator ON operator.id_operator = station_operator.id_operator
    WHERE id_station_operator = $1";

    $result = pg_query_params($connection, $query, array($id));
    $row = pg_fetch_assoc($result);

    $stasiun = "SELECT id_stasiun, nama_stasiun FROM station";

    $result_station = pg_query($connection, $stasiun);

    $option_stasiun = "";

    while($row_stasiun = pg_fetch_assoc($result_station)){
        $option_stasiun .="<option value='{$row_stasiun['id_stasiun']}'>{$row_stasiun['nama_stasiun']}</option>";
    }
?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../includes/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinyMCE.init({
        mode : "textareas",
        theme : "simple",
        editor_selector :"mceEditor",
        paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste : true,
        valid_styles : {'*' : 'color,font-weight,font-style,text-decoration'}

    });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
}
</style>

<div id="tocContainerDalam" class="tocContainerDalam">
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="form.php?mode=edit&id_station_operator=<?=$id;?>"  onSubmit="return check();" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <span class="judul"><img src="../images/icon_list2.gif"><b><?=$judul;?> &rsaquo; <?=$sub_judul;?></b></span>
        <br><br>
        <table cellspacing="1" class="tablesorter" style="width:800px;">
            <tbody>
                <td width="160"></td>
                <td align="right">&nbsp;
                    <span style='color:#ff0000;font-size:12px;'>* </span>required , 
                    <span style='color:#000000;font-size:12px;'>* </span>numeric ,
                    <span style='color:#000000;font-size:12px;'>** </span>integer
                </td>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">
                        <span>ID Stasiun Operator : </span>
                    </td>
                    <td align="left">
                        <input type="hidden" name="id_stasiun_operator" value="<?php echo $row['id_station_operator']?>"/><?php echo $row['id_station_operator']?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">
                        <span>Nama Operator : </span>
                    </td>
                    <td align="left">
                        <?php echo $row['nama_operator']?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">
                        <span>Pilih Stasiun : </span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="id_stasiun" id="id_stasiun">
                            <option value="<?php echo $row['id_stasiun']?>"><?php echo $row['nama_stasiun']?></option>
                            <?php echo $option_stasiun?>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">
                        <span>Keterangan : </span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <textarea name="keterangan" id="keterangan" cols="30" rows="10" value="<?php echo $row['keterangan']?>"><?php echo $row['keterangan']?></textarea>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="Submit" name="submit_true" value="Submit" id="submit_true" class="buttonCari" style="width:80px;"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Output `$queryUpdate`. I'll bet you the `$1` etc. are being interpreted as (undefined) PHP variables.

Comment: I think so(?) but when i tried to use the normal one like ```$id```
It just show an error  ```where id_station_operator = ^```

Comment: Your query definitely needs to be surrounded by single quotes, not double-quotes, so that the dollar signs are passed to the query and not intepreted

Comment: Escape the `$` character, i.e. `\$1`, or use single quotes.

Comment: (and consider switching to PDO and its prepared statements)

Comment: @ceejayoz you'd lose your bet. Also, I don't see how PDO is superior to pg

Comment: @Nicho we cannot debug your code for you. We don't have your server, your database. So we **cannot** tell you what you did or not did wrong. You are supposed to debug your code yourself, and verify every assumption you make. If you select the updated value right here, does it appear updated or not? Did you try to output the parameters? What is this output? What is value of $result?

Comment: @ceejayoz The function pg_query_params() does a much better job then PDO. My advice would be NOT to use PDO when you write code for just PostgreSQL. PDO is a serious limitation for the database.

Comment: See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query-params.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake, i use `id_stasiun_operator` instead of the correct id `id_station_operator`. And now it work properly.

```
<?php
    

    //echo "$id";
    $id = $_GET['id_station_operator '];
    $var_a_st=$_POST['submit_true'];

    $stasiun = "SELECT id_stasiun, nama_stasiun FROM station";

    $result_station = pg_query($connection, $stasiun);

    $option_stasiun = "";

    while($row_stasiun = pg_fetch_assoc($result_station)){
        $option_stasiun .="<option value='{$row_stasiun['id_stasiun']}'>{$row_stasiun['nama_stasiun']}</option>";
    }
    echo "Value of var_a_st: $var_a_st";
    echo "Value of id : $id";
    if($var_a_st == "Submit"){
        $id_stasiun = $_POST['id_stasiun'];
        $keterangan = $_POST['keterangan'];

        $queryUpdate = "UPDATE station_operator SET id_stasiun = $1, keterangan = $2 WHERE id_station_operator = $3";

        $result = pg_query_params($connection, $queryUpdate, array($id_stasiun, $keterangan, $id));

        if(!$result){
            die("Error in SQL query: " . pg_last_error());
        }
        echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV=\"refresh\" content=\"0; URL=list.php\">";
    }
?>
```